# Apply a python decorator to all inheriting classes

Tags: python, django

In my django project (django 1.6 - soon upgrading to 1.9, python 2.7),

I'd like to apply a decorator on all my project's model classes (20-30 classes).
All of these classes already inherit from a parent class called 'LinkableModel', which I wrote for a certain (non-related) purpose.

Now, I'd like to apply a class decorator to all these models.
(specifically I'm referring to decorator 'python_2_unicode_compatible': https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/utils/#django.utils.encoding.python_2_unicode_compatible).

When I add this decorator to their parent class 'LinkableModel', it's not inherited.
Is there any way to apply a decorator to multiple classes, without adding it to each and every class?

(Theoretically I even don't mind if this decorator will be by default applied to all classes in my project...)

Code snippet:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class LinkableModel(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    ...

class MyModel1(LinkableModel):
    ...
    ...
    ...

class MyModel2(LinkableModel):
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Metaclass? `for name, cls in globals().items(): if issubclass(cls, Base): globals()[name] = decorator(cls)`?

Comment: if you decorate the models class migrations will not work.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus Can't get it to work, could you elaborate with a code snippet?

Comment: @AviahLaor I decorated a model class, and south migration still seem to work. Could you explain in what way they will not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the answer by @GingerPlusPlus, and created the following function, to apply a decorator to all subclasses of a class:

```
 def apply_decorator_to_all_subclasses(globals_, base_class, decorator):
    """
    Given a 'globals_' dictionary, a base class, and a decorator - this function applies the decorator to all the defined classes that derive from the base class
    Note!: this function should be called only *after* the subclassess were declared
    :param globals_: the given output of globals(), in the caller's context
    :param base_class: the class whose descendants require the decorator
    :param decorator: the decorator to apply
    """
    for name, cls in globals_.items():
        # Applying only on *class* items, that are descandants of base_class
        if inspect.isclass(cls) and issubclass(cls, base_class) and cls != base_class:
            globals_[name] = decorator(cls)
```

Answer (score 9):

In Python 3.7 now you can do it this way:

```
  class ParentClass:
      def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
          return your_decorator(_cls=cls)
```

it will apply decorator for each subclass of ParentClass

UPDATED: full example:

```
def your_decorator(_cls):
    print("Hello, I'm decor!")
    def wrapper():
        return _cls()
    return wrapper


class ParentClass:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        return your_decorator(_cls=cls)


class A(ParentClass):
    pass

a = A()
```

Comment: I really want this to work, but alas it seems not to in general. It seems to work using dataclasses.dataclass as the decorator (but the return statement from __init_subclass__ is not necessary, it's not clear to me what that return statement achieves), but not when I use any decorator of my own (this must be due to some behaviour of the dataclass framework). I get the feeling this is not designed to work this way, __init_subclass__ is not intended to allow for modification of the child class, rather the parent class.

Comment: @kerzane, hi! Not sure that cause the problem. Maybe full example will be helpful. I updated the answer, pls check. Be sure, that you runs code with Python 3.7 Will be more useful if you attach code that does not work for you

Comment: thanks for your reply! My query is based on the fact that when I add a print statement in the wrapper function:

`    def wrapper():
        print("Hello, I'm wrapper!")
        return _cls()`

That this print statement is not triggered on instantiating an object of class A.

Separately, when I remove the return statement from the __init_subclass__ method, the behaviour of the code is not changed, so I'm not sure the object returned from __init_subclass__ is having the desired result.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is 3.6, not 3.7

Comment: How would this look if I wanted to pass arguments to the decorator? Or if the decorator I want to apply was written by someone else and doesn't have the _cls?

Comment: `__init_subclass__` isn’t supposed to return anything, and the return value is ignored. This only works if the decorator *modifies* `cls`. If it returns a new instance instead, the code will fail. In particular, the concrete example code in this answer does nothing.

Answer (score 3):

There is (as far as I know) no simple way, because you cannot inherit decorators.

The simplest solution I can imagine is:

```
globals_ = globals()
for name, cls in globals_.items():
    if subclass(cls, Base):
        globals_[name] = decorator(cls)
```

It simply iterates over every global variable already defined in current module, and if it happens to be class inheriting from `Base` (or `Base` itself), it decorates it with `decorator`.

Note that subclass will not be decorated if:

- it's created after this snippet,
- it's created in another module,
- it's not defined in global namespace.

Alternatively, you can use metaclass:

```
class Decorate(type):
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, attrs):
        return decorator(super().__new__(name, bases, attrs))

class Base(metaclass=Decorate):
    pass
```

When you write `class Base(metaclass=Decorate):`, Python uses `Decorate` to create `Base` and its subclasses.

All that `Decorate` does, is to decorate class using `decorator` before returning it.

If you use this, you will probably have a problem if you try to inherit from 2 (or more) classes, each with different metaclass.

Comment: chose the first option, although had to change the 3rd line to:     if inspect.isclass(cls) and issubclass(cls, Base) and cls != Base:

Comment: How did you deal with the error "Base is not defined"?