# How can I automatically apply a class decorator to all subclasses?

Tags: python, oop, decorator, metaclass

I have the following code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


class Expr:
    def __repr__(self):
        fields = ', '.join(f'{v!r}' for v in self.__dict__.values())
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({fields})'


@dataclass(repr=False)
class Literal(Expr):
    value: object


@dataclass(repr=False)
class Binary(Expr):
    lhs: Expr
    op: str
    rhs: Expr
```

This code allows me to define expression trees and to `match` against them, e.g.:

```
def fmt_ast(expr: Expr) -> str:
    match expr:
        case Literal(x):
            return str(x)
        case Binary(lhs, op, rhs):
            return f'({op} {fmt_ast(lhs)} {fmt_ast(rhs)})'
    assert False, 'Unreachable'


expr = Binary(Literal(42), '+', Literal(23))
print(fmt_ast(expr))
# (+ 42 23)
```

However, I would like to avoid having to decorate each `Expr` subclass manually. I.e. I want to skip writing `@dataclass(repr=False)`. [Based on another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55490858/1968), I rewrote `Expr` as follows:

```
class Expr:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        dataclass(repr=False)(cls)

    def __repr__(self):
        fields = ', '.join(f'{v!r}' for v in self.__dict__.values())
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({fields})'
```

… and this seems to work (even after removing the decorators from the subclasses). The thing is, I don’t understand *why* it works: sure, I’m invoking the `dataclass` decorator but I’m not *doing* anything with the result, i.e.with the decorated type. I don’t assign it to anything (to what?!) and I don’t return it, since [`__init_subclass__` has no meaningful return value](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__). And yet, the code continues to run as if the subclasses had been decorated with `dataclass`.

However, `mypy` (0.942) calls my bluff:

> ```
> test/__init__.py:29: error: Class "test.Literal" doesn't define "__match_args__"
> test/__init__.py:31: error: Class "test.Binary" doesn't define "__match_args__"
> test/__init__.py:36: error: Too many arguments for "Binary"
> test/__init__.py:36: error: Too many arguments for "Literal"
> ```

I believe that `mypy` is correct, which leaves me with two questions:

1. Why does this seem to work at all?
2. How to do this *properly*, i.e. in a way that satisfies `mypy`, *without* reimplementing the `dataclass` functionality from scratch inside `Expr` or its metaclass?

Comment: This works because `dataclass.dataclass` isn't a *class factory*, it instead mutates the class objet to add the methods, returning the same class object.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That was my initial assumption as well, but in that case shouldn’t `mypy` accept this?

Comment: As for getting this to work with `mypy`, that's another issue. Basically, you want a static type checker to understand dynamically modified code. I think `mypy` generally special-cases the `@dataclass` decorator.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Just like it won't recognize `class Foo: pass` then if you do `def x(self) -> int: return 42` and `Foo.x = x`, it won't recognize `Foo` as having an `x` attribute

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ah, that’s of course possible. I thought `mypy` did evaluate metaclass definitions (and similar things, such as `__init_subclass__`) since it seemed to respond to that, but I might be mistaken about that.

Comment: Note, a new paramter is being [added in 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass), `slots` to generate `__slots__` for you, but this forces it to return a new class, and it would break the above if oyu used it.

Answer (score 2):

@juanpa.arrivillaga has explained in the comments perfectly what is taking place, as put:

- a `dataclass` call modifies the class in place: the same object is mutated so that it gains the new methods and new behaviors.
- `mypy` can't know about the new methods, because it does not run the code: it special cases the `dataclass` decorator, so that in ordinary uses it does know about the new attributes. The workaround there would be adding the methods that dataclass create to `Repr` so that mypy would be fooled.
- some calls to dataclass might return a new object, like when using the new `slots` parameter, in that case, `__init_subclass__` won't help, as dataclass returns a new class, built with base on the one that was passed to it. For the same approach to work, you will have to use a metaclass, and override its `__new__` method, instead (or along with) ordinary inheritance. The `metaclass.__new__` method has to return the actual object that will be used as the class.

```
def __repr__(self):
   # ...
   # stand alone method which will be injected by the metaclass


class MExpr(type):
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, ns):
        cls = super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, ns)
        cls.__repr__ = __repr__
        return dataclass(repr=False, slots=...)(cls)  

class Literal(metaclass=MExpr):
    ...
```

Comment: I’m not averse to writing a metaclass but I’d assume that this won’t help me with mypy, right? Unfortunately there also doesn’t seem to be a way of silencing mypy warnings for all usage of a type, which means that this effectively renders mypy unsable: the output is completely overwhelmed by false positives from these classes. The only approach I can think of is to run mypy through a frontend which filters these warnings.

Comment: If the problem with mypy are the automatic methods created by `@dataclass`. you can resolve it by creating an explicit base class which would use the metaclass, _and_ be decorated with "@dataclass": subclasses of this baseclass will have the metaclass automaticaly applied (and transformed into a dataclass), and the baseclass, having the "phantom" methods, should calm down mypy. 
Another solution is to declare a typing.Protocol and build a baseclass using it as well.

Comment: Note that this breaks when `slots=True` because `dataclasses._add_slots` creates a new class and thus the decorator is applied again, which causes it to complain that `__slots__` is already specified.

Comment: After some more research and several implementation attempts I now *think* this simply can’t be done. The issue I am running into is that mypy complains about “too many positional patterns for class patterns” as well as “too many arguments” when creating new instances derived classes, because there doesn’t seem to be a way of telling mypy about generated `__init__` signatures.

Comment: "Applying a class decorator to all subclasses" can be done, and it is done in the snippet. What can't be done is having a static code analyzer, like mypy, to cope with dynamically created methods and attributes, which is also explained in the answer.

The remaining possibility is to have the metaclass to (or call something to) dynamicallyh generate a ".pyi" file (check PEP 484), which will reflect the new attrbibutes, methods and signatures for the classes. Then that code should be run once before to create these files before mypy would make its checks.