# Type-annotating a curry function

Tags: python, mypy

I'm having a problem annotating a curry function correctly. I use `Concatenate` and `ParamSpec` to catch the first argument to extract, and then I return a function from that. However, `mypy` complains when I try to call the function. A minimal example looks like this:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, ParamSpec, Concatenate
from typing import Callable as Fn, reveal_type

P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")
T = TypeVar("T")


def curry(f: Fn[Concatenate[T, P], R]) -> Fn[[T], Fn[P, R]]:
    """An attempt at currying."""

    def outer(x: T) -> Fn[P, R]:
        def inner(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
            return f(x, *args, **kwargs)

        return inner

    return outer


@curry
def f(x: T, y: int) -> T:
    """Test function."""
    return x


def g(x: T, /) -> Fn[[int], T]:
    """Test function."""
    return lambda _: x

reveal_type(f)
reveal_type(g)
reveal_type(f(1)) # <- this fails in mypy
reveal_type(g(1))
```

I get the impression that `mypy` binds the type variable too early here, so it cannot be bound to the call later, but that is a bit of a wild guess. The playground for `mypy` is [here](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=22c1e6390ee923bad7f99b34a04768ab). In `pyright` the code is checked and understood as I would expect, [playground here](https://pyright-playground.decorator-factory.su/?gzip=H4sIAE2bI2UC_42RwWqEMBCG73mKwVOUdEuvQkvLQs9iQy8iS9ZNRKpRYmz17TuJuqvbSwMyyZ9_vpmMyrQN2KmrdAlV07XGAp86-SkMg0QY0Xx0smBwbHUhrNT4EfU35SjqWpxrCaKHd83AyG8p6hOaJCEJPN9QNEiCkKQoLWVokKLAtwJHgZCLVFAMxkxUxQjNNi1kHJvLGaR5CA8v7jLjeMSYODGPCeAKguBNg7BWNp3FONOw6wPeEG9xNdrBSkPHGPgK85CZsZoqrdEUCVP2MSQHFxlE0dfPqsw7T0hvqW4ZaQejQdERM_aJISF3Ll9nVhfFt4fjePXd-6ko3y2DKUa_9TX59clc9hbUoAtbtdq_dAMbl7mWC-HxOj8E4QR5_j9OLZrzRcApdsTNz6Yq3B3L_VHRp_DO4JVf4E6QtYUCAAA%3D), but unfortunately I need to sneak the code by `mypy` for the QA setup I have in the project I'm working on.

Is there any way I can change the type annotation so `mypy` will accept what I am trying to tell it?

Comment: Unless something changed, [mypy doesn’t execute decorators at all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71801890/1968) so this won’t work, unfortunately. Typed Python and generated code fundamentally don’t mix. Ugh. Yes, this is a major weakness.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to execute the decorator, but it knows the type the decorator says it returns, and I was expecting it to look at that. Maybe it doesn't, though... It just seems to me that it _sometimes_ does, but maybe that is only decorators it knows about in plugins or some such thing.

Comment: This is not about mypy working incorrectly with decorators from what I understand but rather the scope of your `TypeVar` being ambiguous. Basically `T` in `def f(x: T, y: int) -> T:` and in `def curry(f: Fn[Concatenate[T, P], R]) -> Fn[[T], Fn[P, R]]:` can be **different**.

Comment: Well, I'm not claiming that `mypy` is doing the wrong thing (although it is not doing what I expected), but it does seem that `T` is bound in some way that makes the curry function incorrect. And I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: So when I type `x` and the return type for `f` to be an `int` things seem to work properly, but when they are a `TypeVar` (with `f` and `curry` having a different one as well), it errors. Technically I think this should be possible to infer, try raising an issue on their GitHub.

Comment: Run your example on mypy-playground on the master branch (not 1.5.1) with the `—new-type-inference` option turned on

Comment: @dROOOze that combination does the trick, yes. Thanks.