# Type Hint Dynamically Created Subclasses

Tags: python, class, type-hinting, builder, typing

#### Simplified Example

```
class A:
    def __init__(self): ...

class BBuilder:
    # To make this simpler, we won't have any arguments

    def build(self): # -> WhatTypeHintDoIPutHere

        class B(A):
            def __init__(self):
                super().__init__()

        return B

my_b_builder: BBuilder = BBuilder()
BBuilt = my_b_builder.build() # BBuilt: WhatTypeHintDoIPutHere
my_b = BBuilt() # my_b: WhatTypeHintDoIPutHere
```

#### Question

How do I correctly type hint `my_b` and `BBuilt`? Without removing the BBuilder and without replacing the BBuilder with static subclass definitions.

#### What I tried

Tried typehinting `my_b` as:

- Type[A] - incorrect because my_b is an instance
- Type[B] - incorrect because my_b is an instance
- BBuilt - mypy complained - you cannot use variables in typehints
- Using TypeAliases `BBuiltAlias: TypeAlias = BBuilt; my_b: BBuiltAlias` - you cannot use variables in typehints
- Using `type` keyword `type BBuiltAlias = BBuilt; my_b: BBuiltAlias` - you cannot use variables in typehints

Editing the BBuilder to not be a dataclass doesn't change anything
Also experimented with TypeVars - no success. Attempts: [1](https://gist.github.com/JakuWorks/4f1479950d8ba366c535b61cd73cc738) [2](https://gist.github.com/JakuWorks/bca04ea6f88cae2c93d52f356409cdf8) [3](https://gist.github.com/JakuWorks/d23344cf85ba7f79c35652a68cba540d)
Also tried asking ChatGPT - no success

##### Afterword

If you **really** need it [here](https://gist.github.com/JakuWorks/fb905082c27ab74961cc12a3bcb46931) is the original code along with some example usage of the classes. As a side question: Is it a bad coding practice to do this? The original code is easy to edit and easy to use.

Off-topic: My failed attempt of working around this problem [here](https://gist.github.com/JakuWorks/f7be66ac2d2f6128a2bbc5fa0bbf4d13)

Comment: Technically `my_b: A = BBuilt('foo')` is acceptable, according to mypy. The problem with `BBuild(a2='foo')` is that `a2` is not a keyword parameter of the init signature for `A`. But otherwise `BBuild: Type[A] = ...` and `my_b: A = ...` works.

Comment: Static analysis is not amenable to dynamically created types. Here, you can try to type hint it as `A`, but that will come with the problem that `A` doesn't accept that argument

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Contrary to how your comment makes it sound, this isn’t a fundamental property of static analysis, it’s a problem that’s specific to how *Python* implements these things. Other statically typed languages can compute types (at compile time) and subsequently statically verify these. The fact that Python does not support this is a major weakness of the current system. It *should* work, because it is eminently useful (/arguably required).

Comment: I'm not sure it's fair to say it *should* work. It *could*, but the level of detail you need to provide in the type-level descriptions is at least as much work as writing type-safe code in the first place.

Comment: I know providing these type hints takes lots of time. But by asking this question I also want to learn new stuff about python. @chepner :)

Comment: @chepner It *should* work, because the current state of affairs in Python effectively means that computed types (aka. metaprogramming) and static type checking are mutually exclusive: you can use either one or the other but not both. Disabling one of two of the most useful core language features drastically reduces the usefulness of the language as a whole.

Comment: Static typing is not a core feature of Python. Python is a dynamically typed language, will remain so.

Comment: @JakuWorksOfficial It's a fine question; sometimes the answer isn't what you want, though :)

Comment: @chepner Static type checking is all but indispensable for large enough projects. Static type checking has become ubiquitous and has utterly transformed the Python ecosystem, it’s odd to deny this obvious reality.

Comment: Python will support static typing to the extent that it can without making the language itself statically typed. If you can't accept that, Python is not the language you are looking for.

Comment: @chepner That’s completely orthogonal to the point I am making; which is that once you rely on certain, useful type generation features, you cannot use type checking pretty much at all any more, because type errors will propagate through your system. This is an actual, real problem which causes users of Python to forgo dynamic types (rather than static type checking) in many modern projects. And this in turn leads to inferior code. And Python could fix that without giving up either its dynamic nature or static type checking.

Comment: Defining classes inside functions is "fine", except that providing static type hints would be misleading. The reason is that `build` will return a different type each time it is called, even if the type is named the same thing; procedures which rely on `isinstance` and `issubclass` will fail, for example. There might be a strong reason for writing your code like this (and there will be ways to provide a statically-typed solution based on your current code), but I don't see the reason from this example, especially your point about avoiding the need to statically define the classes.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I'm not sure I agree that this kind of thing puts one in a "cannot use type checking pretty much at all anymore" situation -- the type system has protocols and structural subtyping; you can assert "A will have properties B, C and D" even in cases where one can't assert "A is a B".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Protocols don’t help if the static type checker does not know about members that are generated via metaprogramming. For a very simple example, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/71771725/1968.

Answer (score 0):

**Even though this is possible, dynamically creating classes (according to many people) may bring some nasty problems. There probably are other ways to solve your problem without dynamic class definitions!**

The answer turned out to be extremely simple.

#### Example

```
from typing import Type

# To make this a little simpler, we will not define any arguments for the init functions.
# It would not be that hard if you wanted to introduce arguments


class ABase:  # We want to subclass ABase and overwrite its init
    def __init__(self) -> None:  # We want to call this init in our dynamically created class!
        print("ABase Init")
        ...  # Imagine lots of code here

    def uncool(self) -> None:  # This method is uncool. We want our final subclass to overwrite it and make it cooler
        print("Uncool (we should not see this message because its uncool and this method will be overwritten)")

    def a_cool(self) -> None:  # This method is cool! We want our final subclass to support it!
        print("A_Cool Is there really no other way to solve your problem than creating classes dynamically?")


class BReal(ABase):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        print("BReal Init")
        ...  # Imagine lots of code here

    def b_cool(self) -> None:  # This method is also cool! we want our final subclass to support it!
        print("B_Cool")

    def uncool(self) -> None:
        print("Uncool is now cool because it has been overwritten! So we can now see its message!")

    # Define all the methods and functionality you want the final dynamically-created Subclass to support
    # Basically treat BReal almost as if it WAS the final dynamically-created Subclass


class BClassBuilder:

    def build(self) -> Type[BReal]:  # Since the B class is 100% compatible with BReal. There is no problem with using the Type[BReal] typehint
        class B(BReal): ...

        return B  # Yay! B is now dynamically created

        # KEEP IN MIND THIS IS JUST SOME BASIC PROOF-OF-CONCEPT CODE
        # I KEPT THIS AS SIMPLE AS POSSIBLE
        # But don't be fooled, this simple design took me a day to figure out


our_builder: BClassBuilder = BClassBuilder()
BBuilt: Type[BReal] = our_builder.build()  # Since the B class is 100% compatible with BReal. There is no problem with using the `Type[BReal]` typehint

print("\nTesting Inits")
our_b: BReal = BBuilt()  # Instance of our dynamically created B class!

print("\nTesting Methods")
our_b.a_cool()  # InteliSense WORKED
our_b.b_cool()  # InteliSense WORKED
our_b.uncool()  # InteliSense WORKED

"""OUTPUT

Testing Inits
ABase Init
BReal Init

Testing Methods
A_Cool Is there really no other way to solve your problem than creating classes dynamically?
B_Cool
Uncool is now cool because it has been overwritten! So we can now see its message!
"""  # EVERYTHING WORKS AND THERE ARE 0 COMPLAINTS FROM PYLANCE AND MYPY
```

#### Explanation

I don't think much explanation is necessary due to the number of comments in the example. I will give a short explanation of what is happening:

1. First we define the class we want to subclass as `ABase`
2. Then we statically create a subclass of `ABase` named `BReal` ('real' because this is really the part where you write the code). Our dynamically created class will simply subclass the BReal and therefore inherit all of its methods and whatever else.
3. In the example now we add some means of dynamically defining a class. I chose a Class Builder (this is probably not a real term, nor a professional term).
4. Defining that dynamically created subclass of A is very simple. Let's name it B. `class B(BReal): ...` We use ... on purpose because there is no real code we should write here.

Note for people newer to python who want B to support arguments in its init:
Since the way we defined B makes it a 100% subclass of BReal without any differences, it also inherits BReal's `init`! So if you want B to support arguments, edit BReal's `init`. Leave B's `init` undefined!

5. Now simply use the code you've written to dynamically define a class and save it to a variable.
   Please read the code of the Example if you want to see how to typehint that variable and an instance of B.

**Even though this is possible, dynamically creating classes (according to many people) may bring some nasty problems. There probably are other ways to solve your problem without dynamic class definitions!**

As an off-topic: I decided to remove dynamic class definitions in favour of something much simpler from my code: [code](https://gist.github.com/JakuWorks/8876dfda24a2ba41af71e1f03ff161b7)